# MongoDB - How to use substitute value when there is missing field-and-value pair

Tags: mongodb

I have documents in MongoDB Atlas with this structure:

```json
{
   "_id":"32013R0345",
   "name_lang":{
      "de":"Verordnung (EU) Nr. 345/2013 des Europäischen Parlaments und des Rates vom 17. April 2013 über Europäische Risikokapitalfonds  Text von Bedeutung für den EWR",
      "en":"Regulation (EU) No 345/2013 of the European Parliament and of the Council of 17 April 2013 on European venture capital funds  Text with EEA relevance",
      "fr":"Règlement (UE) n ° 345/2013 du Parlement européen et du Conseil du 17 avril 2013 relatif aux fonds de capital-risque européens  Texte présentant de l'intérêt pour l'EEE"
   },
   "proposedAmendments":[
      {
         "id_doc":"52016PC0461",
         "name_lang":{
            "de":"Vorschlag für eine VERORDNUNG DES EUROPÄISCHEN PARLAMENTS UND DES RATES zur Änderung der Verordnung (EU) Nr. 345/2013 über Europäische Risikokapitalfonds und der Verordnung (EU) Nr. 346/2013 über Europäische Fonds für soziales Unternehmertum",
            "en":"Proposal for a REGULATION OF THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND OF THE COUNCIL amending Regulation (EU) No 345/2013 on European venture capital funds and Regulation (EU) No 346/2013 on European social entrepreneurship funds",
            "fr":"Proposition de RÈGLEMENT DU PARLEMENT EUROPÉEN ET DU CONSEIL modifiant le règlement (UE) nº 345/2013 relatif aux fonds de capital-risque européens et le règlement (UE) nº 346/2013 relatif aux fonds d'entrepreneuriat social européens"
         }
      },
      {
         "id_doc":"52018PC0110",
         "name_lang":{
            "de":"Vorschlag für eine VERORDNUNG DES EUROPÄISCHEN PARLAMENTS UND DES RATES zur Erleichterung des grenzüberschreitenden Vertriebs von Investmentfonds und zur Änderung der Verordnungen (EU) Nr. 345/2013 und (EU) Nr. 346/2013",
            "en":"Proposal for a REGULATION OF THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND OF THE COUNCIL on facilitating cross-border distribution of collective investment funds and amending Regulations (EU) No 345/2013 and (EU) No 346/2013",
            "fr":"Proposition de RÈGLEMENT DU PARLEMENT EUROPÉEN ET DU CONSEIL visant à faciliter la distribution transfrontière des fonds communs de placement et modifiant les règlements (UE) nº 345/2013 et (UE) nº 346/2013"
         }
      },
      {
         "id_doc":"52021PC0725",
         "name_lang":{
            "en":"Proposal for a REGULATION OF THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND OF THE COUNCIL amending certain Regulations as regards the establishment and functioning of the European single access point"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I am fetching the document to display it in the frontend. In case of *proposedAmendments* when there is no *name_lang*  field-and-value pair other then *en* (English) title I would like to create missing languages fields and to project English title as a substitute, this is important because of internalization features. The languague is set dynamiclay as `${l}`. So the expected projection or aggregation of *proposedAmendments* for example for French should look like this:

```json
{
   "_id":"32013R0345",
   "name_lang":{
      "fr":"Règlement (UE) n ° 345/2013 du Parlement européen et du Conseil du 17 avril 2013 relatif aux fonds de capital-risque européens  Texte présentant de l'intérêt pour l'EEE"
   },
   "proposedAmendments":[
      {
         "id_doc":"52016PC0461",
         "name_lang":{
            "fr":"Proposition de RÈGLEMENT DU PARLEMENT EUROPÉEN ET DU CONSEIL modifiant le règlement (UE) nº 345/2013 relatif aux fonds de capital-risque européens et le règlement (UE) nº 346/2013 relatif aux fonds d'entrepreneuriat social européens"
         }
      },
      {
         "id_doc":"52018PC0110",
         "name_lang":{
            "fr":"Proposition de RÈGLEMENT DU PARLEMENT EUROPÉEN ET DU CONSEIL visant à faciliter la distribution transfrontière des fonds communs de placement et modifiant les règlements (UE) nº 345/2013 et (UE) nº 346/2013"
         }
      },
      {
         "id_doc":"52021PC0725",
         "name_lang":{
            "fr":"Proposal for a REGULATION OF THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND OF THE COUNCIL amending certain Regulations as regards the establishment and functioning of the European single access point"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I have tried different combinations of MongoDB $eq, $cond and other possible expressions but without any luck. This is my basic code I need to update.

```js
    let l = "fr";
    ...
    let doc = await collection
      .find({ _id: "32013R0345" })
      .project({
        _id: 1,
        [`name_lang.${l}`]: 1,
        [`proposedAmendments.id_doc`]: 1,
        [`proposedAmendments.name_lang.${l}`]: 1,
        ...
        ...
      })
      .toArray();
```

Thank everyone for any help.

Comment: Are the candidates of languages only limited to de, fr, en? Also, which version of MongoDB you are using?

Comment: Using recent MongoDB Atlas. In reality the languages may vary, only sure thing is that there will be always English version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to [Wernfried Domscheit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit) who showed me the way. After some attempts this code seems to work for me.

```js
let l = "fr";
let document = await db.collection.aggregate([{
            $match: {
                _id: "32013R0345"
            }
        },
        {
            $set: {
                "proposedAmendments": {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$proposedAmendments",
                        as: "proposedamendments",
                        in: {
                            $mergeObjects: [
                                "$$proposedamendments",
                                {
                                    name_lang: {
                                        [`${l}`]: {
                                            $ifNull: [
                                                `$$proposedamendments.name_lang.${l}`,
                                                "$$proposedamendments.name_lang.en",
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                [`name_lang.${l}`]: 1,
                proposedAmendments: 1
            }
        }
    ])
    .toArray();

console.dir(document, {
    depth: null
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { _id: "32013R0345" } },
   // convert to { k: , v: } arrays
   {
      $set: {
         // available languages are taken from parent, not proposedAmendments, see below
         languages: { $map: { input: { $objectToArray: "$name_lang" }, in: "$$this.k" } },
         proposedAmendments: {
            $map: {
               input: "$proposedAmendments",
               as: "amendment",
               in: {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                     "$$amendment",
                     { en: "$$amendment.name_lang.en" },
                     { name_lang: { $objectToArray: "$$amendment.name_lang" } }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   // replace missing languages by English
   {
      $set: {
         "proposedAmendments": {
            $map: {
               input: "$proposedAmendments",
               as: "amendment",
               in: {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                     "$$amendment",
                     {
                        name_lang: {
                           $map: {
                              input: "$languages",
                              as: "l",
                              in: {
                                 $ifNull: [
                                    { $first: { $filter: { input: "$$amendment.name_lang", as: "lang", cond: { $eq: ["$$lang.k", "$$l"] } } } },
                                    { k: "$$l", v: "$$amendment.en" }
                                 ]
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unset: ["proposedAmendments.en", "languages"] },
   // convert back from { k: , v: } arrays
   {
      $set: {
         "proposedAmendments": {
            $map: {
               input: "$proposedAmendments",
               as: "amendment",
               in: {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                     "$$amendment",
                     { name_lang: { $arrayToObject: "$$amendment.name_lang" } }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

This solution is very generic, it works for any number of languages.

If you need to retrieve the languages from proposedAmendments instead from parent then use:

```
languages: {
   $setUnion: {
      $reduce: {
         input: { $map: { input: { $map: { input: "$proposedAmendments", in: { $objectToArray: "$$this.name_lang" } } }, in: "$$this.k" } },
         initialValue: [],
         in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] },
      }
   }
}
```

This part

```
{
   $mergeObjects: [
      "$$amendment",
      { name_lang: ... }
   ]
}
```

also supports generic proposedAmendments. If the proposedAmendmentsalways have only field `id_doc` and `name_lang`, then you could also use simpler

```
{
   id_doc: "$$amendment.id_doc",
   name_lang: ...
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xg3jcQLei6p)

A much more static version is this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { _id: "32013R0345" } },
   {
      $set: {
         "proposedAmendments": {
            $map: {
               input: "$proposedAmendments",
               as: "amendment",
               in: {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                     "$$amendment",
                     {
                        name_lang: {
                           en: "$$amendment.name_lang.en",
                           de: { $ifNull: ["$$amendment.name_lang.de", "$$amendment.name_lang.en"] },
                           fr: { $ifNull: ["$$amendment.name_lang.fr", "$$amendment.name_lang.en"] }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

**Update**

If you like to output only a single language, replace `input: "$languages"` by `input: ["fr"]` or replace 3rd stage by this:

```
  {
    $set: {
      "proposedAmendments": {
        $map: {
          input: "$proposedAmendments",
          as: "amendment",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$amendment",
              {
                name_lang: [
                  {
                    $ifNull: [
                      {
                        $first: {
                          $filter: {
                            input: "$$amendment.name_lang",
                            as: "lang",
                            cond: { $eq: [ "$$lang.k", "fr" ] }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      { k: "fr", v: "$$amendment.en" }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Of course, `"fr"` can be replaced by your `${l}`

And a solution if you prefer dynamic query compose:

```
var name_lang = {}
name_lang[`${l}`] = { '$ifNull': [`$$amendment.name_lang.${l}`, "$$amendment.name_lang.en"] }
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { _id: "32013R0345" } },
   {
      $set: {
         "proposedAmendments": {
            $map: {
               input: "$proposedAmendments",
               as: "amendment",
               in: {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                     "$$amendment",
                     { name_lang: name_lang }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: It does not change anything, it is "only" a query.

Comment: Sorry, you are right.

Comment: [Wernfried Domscheit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit)      I have edited the question to highlight that I have to use dynamic value for  language and also that the result should be only in that language. Your proposed solution also destroyed all other queries I am suing where dynamic  language are needed

Comment: Please see my update. What do you mean by "Your proposed solution also destroyed all other queries"

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience. I have a very very  long query in fact. I am using dynamic `${l}` to use langue in a query dynamically according  to a user`s set up in front end. The are nearly  30 languages versions for every title, name, etc. so this is way to filler and fetch only the language the user uses.

Comment: [Wernfried Domscheit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit) Throws this error: _query failed: (Location28651) PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: input to $filter must be an array not object_ I also do not get your lang definition hereabove, the language will be defined by user in the frontend (dropdown menu in UI).

Comment: I don't get your point. `l` is a variable you set to `"fr"` - or whatever the user will select. The query should work with, provided the input data is as given in your example.